# Integral of constant divided by polynomial and logarithm

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

$$\int_e^\infty\frac{2}{x-\ln(x)}\mathrm dx$$

I'm not sure how to integrate. What are your hints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$\int_{e}^{\infty}\frac{2}{x-\ln{(x)}}\,\mathrm{d}x>\int_{e}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x$$

Comment: Why not use 2/x as the comparison?

Comment: @Jeffrey That works too.